# Reading Barcodes with PixelSense

Tags: barcode, pixelsense

How can I read a standard barcode, using the Microsoft PixelSense, and act upon it in code?

I wish to create something similar to the bit codes within the `TagVisualizer`, but want to be able to a standard bar code (off the back of an employee id).  Is the PixelSense able to extract this information and provide me a number, or any amount of information that I might be able to parse apart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard barcodes have too much detail to be recognized by Microsoft Pixelsense. You will need an external device to read them. From the [Tagged objects for ms surface 2.0 whitepaper](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28959)

> Barcode Support
>
> A barcode is an optical machine-readable
>   representation of data typically used for scanning products or
>   tracking inventory. The most common barcode is the UPC code used for
>   scanning products at point of sale terminals. The best barcode
>   integration for Surface uses a **dedicated external barcode scanning device**
>   that can be built into the Surface enclosure, connecting to the
>   unit via USB. Surface does not support displaying barcodes for
>   scanning by external devices.